# Android Paging Library loadAfter() not called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, paging, android-jetpack

Let me just give a short overview on what I'm trying to do. So basically, I am new to this Paging Library in Android Jetpack and I'm trying to implement a paged list. The backend already did the part of paginating by request (*The backend returns 25 items per page as default*) so all I need to do is make a request and specify a page I want to display and then the items I needed will then be returned. I was able to display and make the `loadInitial()` work but after I scroll to the lowest item it won't fire the `loadAfter()`.

My `PagedListAdapter` and `RecyclerView` is very straight forward so I don't think posting it here would help. The `onCreateViewHolder` returns a ViewHolder by Data Binding. The `onBindViewHolder` just calls a method inside my viewholder and set the items. I'm not overriding the `getItem()` method. That's about it for my adapter and the `DiffCallback`.

However, below are my other code snippets. Note that I have modified the variable and method names for privacy.

**My Config for the LivePagedListBuilder**:

```
public MyViewModel() {
    PagedList.Config config =
        new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(1)
            .setPrefetchDistance(1)
            .build();

    items = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(myDataSourceFactory, config).build();
}

public LiveData<PagedList<Item>> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

**The way I observe the LiveData in my View**:

```
viewModel.getItems().observe(this, items -> {
  adapter.submitList(items);
});
```

**My Data Source**: 
ItemKeyedDataSource

```
private int defaultPage = 1;

public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull 
 LoadInitialCallback<Item> callback) {

    remoteRepository.getItems(String.valueOf(defaultPage))
    ...
}

public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Item> callback) {

    remoteRepository.getItems(String.valueOf(params.key))
    ...
}

public Integer getKey(@NonNull Item item) {
    return defaultPage++;
}
```